# A little help in mobile app sector - question

Tags: android, ios, cordova, mobile, push-notification

I am new in mobile app sector and I think about applications which contains google  maps, can be available for Android/iOS (i do not have any experience in Objective-C/Swift, Android), has notifications between devices.

For google maps I did some research and I know that I have to google account for using google maps API. I will be able to display devices on the map in real time. How to find device in some radius?

For notification I know that there is Firebase but I have not used it. I saw it have REST API.

For application I want to use Apache Cordova (I know there is PhoneGap too).

I have backend in Java. I thought about something like this:

```
Device <-- REST--> JAVA (server/DB) <-- REST--> (Firebase)/(Google Maps API)
```

Is it possible to send notification device <-> device in my configuration?

Does Firebase need his own DB for user/device etc?

I thought about when someone open the app will see available other devices on map and will be able to "tap" on one of them and send it a notification. Is it possible?

Maybe someone can give some tips/links/knowledge about how i can achieve this or how it supposed to be done.

Thanks

Comment: Not down voter. While you are on the right track, you'll need to learn more about mobile development as Cordova is Phonegap and that framework uses Javascript. Firebase is a catch all name for a variety of services including a data store. You are asking a lot of "can I" questions which isn't what SO is good for.

Answer (score 0):

> How to find device in some radius?

You tell the server with your backend your location, it responds with a list of devices that are "in some radius" (by executing some code that does whatever you define that to mean).

> Is it possible to send notification device <-> device in my configuration?

This is never really possible (or done that way). Notifications always come from servers from Apple or Google. If you want to trigger a notification from device 1 to device 2, device 1 would tell the server about it, then the server would tell the push provider who then tells Apple or Google to send a notification to device 2. (Which of course means that device 1 has to be able to identify device 2 somehow, and that the backend has to know about both of these and have a push token for device 2 saved so that it can tell the push provider to send a push there.)

> Does Firebase need his own DB for user/device etc?

Firebase is a platform that offers multiple services. One of those is to send push notifications, another is a database to store information about device or users. So no, it doesn't need "his own DB" but there will have to be a database about users or their devices to be able to send notifications.

> I thought about when someone open the app will see available other devices on map and will be able to "tap" on one of them and send it a notification. Is it possible?

That is technically possible, although not in this direct way you described, but what I elaborated above.